# How to enhance small Haskell Code Snippet

Tags: list, haskell

just recently I started to try out haskell. 
It's fun trying out different exercises, but sometimes I get the feeling, that my found solutions are far from elegant: The following Code Snipplet will find the longest sub-sequence in a list, which will satisfy a given condition (for example uppercase letters etc.)

Could you help a noob to make everything shorter and more elegant - every advice is highly appreciated.

```
import           Data.Char

longer :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
longer x y = if length x > length y
             then x
             else y

longest :: [[a]]->[a]
longest  = foldl longer []

nextSequence :: (a->Bool) -> [a] ->([a],[a])
nextSequence f x = span f (dropWhile (not . f) x)


longestSubsequence :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
longestSubsequence _ x | null x = []
longestSubsequence f x =
     longest $  (\y -> [fst y , longestSubsequence f $ snd y]) (nextSequence f x)


testSequence :: String
testSequence = longestSubsequence Data.Char.isUpper
    "hkerhklehrERJKJKJERKJejkrjekERHkhkerHERKLJHERJKHKJHERdjfkj"
```

Comment: Not sure if this is 100% what you're looking for, but the standard library function [takeWhile](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile) does exactly this. (I see your implementation uses its close relative `dropWhile`.) Note that the implementation of `takeWhile` is a very simple recursive definition, you definitely don't need all these auxiliary functions!

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thank you for your reply. I would love to get rid of all these auxilary functions, but just don't know how. First I used takeWhile - but with span it seemed simpler. If I understand correctly takeWhile -starts listing all elements from the start of the list where the condidtion applies, but what I'm searching is the longest sublist for which the conditions apply - so for example: aaaaaaaBBBBBBaaaaaBBBBBBBBBBcccccDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDaaaa should return DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD. Is it possible to do this in just one small functions?

Comment: oh I see, sorry. I had thought you just wanted to write your own version of `takeWhile` (without being sure that you didn't know it already existed)

Comment: I've added a shortened version to my answer in addition to the previous ones, maybe you'll like it

Comment: @YuriKovalenko Hey from all the suggestions your shortened version seems to be the best, I really like it!

Comment: @MarwanSabih I'm glad that you liked it. If so, could you mark it as an accepted answer?

Comment: @YuriKovalenko Sorry took me some time but here you go ... didn't know you can only accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you can define your `longest` like this:

```
import Data.Function
import Data.List

longest :: [[a]] -> [a]
longest = maximumBy (compare `on` length)
```

And to get all subsequences that satisfy a given condition you can write a function like this:

```
import Data.List

getSatisfyingSubseqs :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
getSatisfyingSubseqs f = filter (f . head) . groupBy same 
    where same x y = f x == f y
```

Here we group elements where the condition yields the same result and filter only subsequences that satisfy the condition.

In the total:

```
longestSubsequence :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
longestSubsequence f = longest . getSatisfyingSubseqs f
```

UPDATE: And if you want to make it shorter, you can just throw out the auxiliary functions and write the whole at a time:

```
longestSubsequence :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
longestSubsequence f = maximumBy (compare `on` length) . filter (f . head) . groupBy same 
    where same x y = f x == f y
```

(Don't forget the imports)
You can run it there: https://repl.it/@Yuri12358/so-longestsequence

Answer (score 1):

The [span :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:span) function could be very handy here. Also note that `f <$> (a,b) = (a,f b)`. Probably not very efficient due to the `length` checks but it should do the job.

```
lss :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
lss f []        = []
lss f ls@(x:xs) = if f x then longer (lss f <$> span f ls)
                         else lss f xs
                  where
                  longer ::([a],[a]) -> [a]
                  longer (xs,ys) = if length xs >= length ys then xs else ys
```

Comment: Thank you! Wow that's amazingly short :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `longer` function uses `length`, which means it doesn't work if either input is infinite. However, it can be improved to work when at most one is infinite:

```
longer l1 l2 = go l1 l2
  where
    go [] _ = l2
    go _ [] = l1
    go (_:xs) (_:ys) = go xs ys
```

This is also a performance optimization. Before, if you had a 10-element list and a 10-million-element list, it would walk through all 10 million elements of the 10-million-element list before returning it. Here, it will return it as soon as it gets to the 11th element instead.

Comment: Thank you! This is quite handy didn't thought about lists and the performance at all :)